# Fetching and Parsing proxies from URLs in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, http-proxy

I tried to fetch and parse proxies from different proxy lists websites.
Here's what I've came up to so far:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import sys
import re


proxies = []
def fetchAndParseProxies(url, custom_regex):
    n = 0
    try:
        proxylist = requests.get(url, timeout=15).text
        proxylist = proxylist.replace('null', '"N/A"')
        custom_regex = custom_regex.replace('%ip%', '([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3})')
        custom_regex = custom_regex.replace('%port%', '([0-9]{1,5})')
        for proxy in re.findall(re.compile(custom_regex), proxylist):
            proxies.append(proxy[0] + ":" + proxy[1])
            n += 1
    except:
        sys.stdout.write("{0: >5} proxies fetched from {1}\n".format('0',url))

proxysources = [
    ["http://spys.one/en","tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    #["http://www.httptunnel.ge/ProxyListForFree.aspx"," target=\"_new\">%ip%:%port%</a>"],
    #["https://www.us-proxy.org/", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    #["https://free-proxy-list.net/", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    #["https://www.sslproxies.org/", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    #["https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v0/get?l=en&t=https", '"IP": "%ip%", "PORT": "%port%",'],
    #["https://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=getproxies&proxytype=http&timeout=5000&country=all&anonymity=elite&ssl=all", "%ip%:%port%"],
    #["http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/http/ping/level1", "<tr><td>%IP%<\\/td><td>%Port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    ["https://www.proxy-list.download/HTTPS", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    ["https://www.proxy-list.download/HTTP", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    ["http://www.freeproxylists.net/", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    ["https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
    ["http://www.freeproxylists.net/", "<tr><td>%ip%<\\/td><td>%port%<\\/td><td>(.*?){2}<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td>.*?<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><td class='hx'>(.*?)<\\/td><td class='hm'>.*?<\\/td><\\/tr>"],
]

loop = tqdm(total=len(proxysources), position=0, leave=False)
for source in proxysources:
    loop.set_description('fetching...')
    fetchAndParseProxies(source[0], source[1])
    loop.update(1)
loop.close()

print(len(proxies)," Proxies Fetched.")
```

My Output :

```
0  Proxies Fetched.
```

As you can see, the problem is that it says `0  Proxies Fetched` for the uncommented lines even though the website structure is the same from what I've looked. I must have done an error in my regex but I can't find where.

I would greatly appreciate some help.
In the meantime, I'll continue to look at it and post updates if I've got some.

Comment: Can you use `beautifulsoup` to parse the proxy sites?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I've never used  ```beautifulsoup``` before, so I don't know if that's possible or not, but I'll take a look at it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will get proxies from `http://sps.one/en`, but similar approach can be used for other proxy-lists:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


ports_url = 'http://spys.one/proxy-port/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(ports_url, headers=headers, data={'xpp': 5}).content, 'html.parser')
for f in soup.select('td[colspan="2"] > a > font.spy6'):
    u = 'http://spys.one/proxy-port/' + f.text + '/'
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(u, headers=headers, data={'xpp': 5}).content, 'html.parser')
    for ff in s.select('tr > td:nth-child(1) > font.spy14'):
        print(ff.text)
```

Prints:

```
81.17.131.61:8080
200.108.183.2:8080
105.209.182.128:8080
45.77.63.202:8080
94.158.152.54:8080
50.233.228.147:8080
142.44.148.56:8080
52.138.1.43:8080
68.183.202.221:8080
103.52.135.60:8080
104.238.174.173:8080
181.129.219.133:8080
183.89.147.40:8080
51.38.71.101:8080
103.112.61.162:8080
131.221.228.9:8080
49.0.65.246:8080
45.32.176.57:8080
104.238.185.153:8080
155.138.146.210:8080
203.76.124.35:8080
182.253.6.234:8080
36.90.93.20:8080
207.182.135.52:8080
165.16.109.50:8080
202.142.178.98:8080
103.123.246.66:8080
185.36.157.30:8080
103.104.213.227:8080
68.188.63.149:8080
136.244.113.206:3128
54.39.91.84:3128
198.13.36.75:3128
93.153.173.102:3128
161.35.110.112:3128

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  it runs smoothly. Is it possible to change with beautiful soup the number of shown proxies in the show dropbox ?

Comment: @Unicyclist I updated my answer, now it shows 500 proxies each port.

Comment: Thank you very much ! So the xpp corresponds to the option for the selector, If I understood correctly.

Comment: @Unicyclist Yes, it's POST data that is sent to the server. You can observe what is sent to the server by opening Firefox Developer Tools -> Network tab (Chrome has something similar too).